# Avoid extra whitespace when pasting vertical selection

Tags: vim, vi

I often need to copy larger vertical selections e.g. when working with
(let's stay civilized) "getter/setter"-rich interfaces, e.g

```
A very long line with something I would like to copy: ABC$
A short line with nothing$
A very long line with something I would like to copy: ABC$
```

Here I have used `$` to indicated the end of the line. I now make a visual
vertical selection on e.g. the `A` in the column 55 across all lines, yank it
and paste it with `P` before that column and get extra whitespace inserted in
the second line.

```
A very long line with something I would like to copy: AABC$
A short line with nothing                              $
A very long line with something I would like to copy: AABC$
```

Is there a way to avoid the extra whitespace? *Changing* characters in the vertical visual
selection doesn't seem to suffer from this issue.

Comment: No matter what I do I'm not able to copy the extra whitespace ... what version of vim and environment?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I see this for 7.3.931 and 7.3.1070 even when using `-u /dev/null` in the terminal version. The readline versions must be wildly different, but didn't check.

Comment: What does `:verbose set virtualedit?` produce? How are you yanking text: `v`, `V`, or `<c-v>`? I can produce this by yanking a visual block and `set virtualedit=all`. I imagine `set virtualedit=block` would have the same effect. Quick fix: yanking lines line-wise with `V`.

Comment: @PeterRincker: `virtualedit=`. I mark a *vertical* visual selection with `<C-v>` and yanking with either `y` or `Y` produces the same result.

Comment: Have tried using `$`, like: `<C-v>$`, then whatever motion to select desired lines?

Comment: @demure The OP is only trying to copy a single column. Notice how in his example the ABC turned into AABC at the end of the line.

Answer (score 4):

This is how visual-block move works. You are copying column 55. Then pasting with `P`. Your second line does not extend as far as column 55. So when you paste it will extend that line for you.

Use `:reg` to look at your register. You will noticed `A^J ^JA` as the value for `""`, the unnamed register. The `^J` symbolize line breaks. Notice the space between `^J`'s. This is how a visual-block mode yank works with empty space, by filling it in with spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Regarding my question: Is there way to avoid the "autoextending" of shorter lines when yanking? I know how to trim whitespace at EOL, but would like to avoid this since I work with mere mortals and don't want to introduce formatting changes when changing functionality.

Comment: There is no way to stop the auto-extending that I am aware of. Trim the white space via `:'[,']s/\s*$//` right after you paste. I think visual-block mode is probably not the right solution for this case. I suggest you look at substitution (`:h :s`) and/or macros (`:h q`).

Comment: Argh, trimming would get rid of existing excess whitespace. I guess it's time to retrain my muscle memory if no solution comes up here.

Comment: as said above, visual-block is not the solution. OTOH substitution works… `:%s/\(.\{54\}\)\(.\)/\1\2\2/`